# stristr php function doesn't work as it should

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, strstr

```
for($check = 0; $check<12;$check++)
{
    echo "<strong>" .$cars[$check] .":</strong>";

    foreach($models as $model)
    {

        if ( stristr($model, $cars[$check]))

        {
            echo $model;
        }
    }

}
```

$cars is an array that contains 12 vehicle makes, $models is a large array (about 3000 elements) which contains many models of different car makes. 
I expect from my code to echo the model name if it can find the name of the car ($cars[$check]) in it. The problem is that it returns nothing, but if I replace the "$cars[$check]" in the if function with a static string like "BMW", then it has no problem in returning the models that contain the string "BMW". I tried everything for hours and searched the internet in and out and couldn't find a solution. Is it something wrong with the code, or have approached this in a wrong way?

Comment: what are the formats of your `$models` and `$cars` arrays? You might have undefined index/variable errors in PHP that might be killing your script, which would explain nothing being returned.

Comment: What's the value of `$cars`? Please use `var_dump` on it and post the result as an edit to your post.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `foreach` for the cars model as well, and use a key instead of `$check`: You keep a natural association with the key and value doing this so you can't break it by having `$check` being an undefined index (and killing your PHP execution in some instances)

```
foreach($cars as $check => $car) {

    echo "<strong>" . $car . "</strong>";
    foreach($models as $model) {
        if(stristr($model, $car))
            echo $model;
    }

}
```

--edit-- if you are only expecting one model to be assigned to each car, and you have lots of models, you should cut down your server processing by using `continue` after your `echo $model`. This will skip the iteration of the **car's** foreach loop and move on to the next.

```
if(stristr($model, car)) {
    echo $model;
    continue 2;
}
```